# Working of Await and signal in concurrent Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I am a beginner and I have to write a code for particular prob stmt. I wanna use locks to implement it. Beforehand, I gotto know the working of locks and its methods.

In my below code, I need the first thread to await and second thread to signal the first thread and wake up. But the signal is not waking up my waiting thread. Could anyone pls help.

```
package com.java.ThreadDemo;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadEx {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ThreadMy mt[]=new ThreadMy[6];
        int a=1, b=2;
        mt[1] = new ThreadMy(a);
        mt[2] = new ThreadMy(b);
        mt[1].start ();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        mt[2].start ();
    }   
}
class ThreadMy extends Thread
{
    final ReentrantLock  rl = new ReentrantLock() ;
    Condition rCond = rl.newCondition();
    //private final Condition wCond = rl.newCondition();

    int i;
    int c;

    public ThreadMy(int a)
    {
        c=a;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.print("\nThread "+c+" "+rl.isHeldByCurrentThread()+" "+rl.isLocked() );
        rl.lock();
    try
    {
    //for (i=0;i<2;i++)

    System.out.print("\nThread "+c+" "+rl.isHeldByCurrentThread()+" "+rl.getHoldCount() );
    try
    {
        if (c==1)
        {       
            System.out.print("await\n");
            rCond.await();
            //rCond.await(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            System.out.print("signal\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("P");
            rCond.signal();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.print("P1");
        }
        //rCond.signal();
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException e)
    {
        //System.out.print("Exception ");

        }

    }
    finally
    {
         rl.unlock();
    }
        System.out.print("\n run " + c);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be creating one lock per thread?

Comment: No.. All I am wanting to do is, allow one thread to go thru while the other waits until the thread1 finishes its job. And the waiting thread wakes up and continues its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sharing lock and condition between threads. Each instance of ThreadMy is running with its own lock and condition object.

Comment: So How am I supposed to modify the code for sharing the lock and condition?

Comment: Whoa.. It is working :) Thanks a lot.. Now I am catching up with the things you have added. Could you pls explain this?